# Is Processing Section 508 compliant?

Tags: processing, section508

Is Processing ADA 508 compliant or has a VPAT? We need to confirm that to install it on computers in our organization.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly does it mean to be ADA 508 compliant or have a VPAT? Can you provide a list of requirements?

Comment: This is a question you should be asking over on https://github.com/processing/processing, or https://discourse.processing.org, directly addressing the people that make it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I agree that the question might be more fruitfully asked there, but given the existence of the `section508` tag, I don't see how the question is really off-topic here. Perhaps that tag needs guidelines about its proper scope.

Comment: I didn't say it was off topic, but part of posting to SO is making sure you _first_ try the most obvious places (as part of the "search and research" step of ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask)), which in this case is asking the people who make Processing, which given that it's open source are _super_ easy to contact.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to check with [processing.org](https://processing.org/) rather than (or in addition to) Stack Overflow. Here is a very recent discussion about the issue: [Processing Voluntary Product Accessibility Template (V.P.A.T.)](https://discourse.processing.org/t/processing-voluntary-product-accessibility-template-v-p-a-t/8400) on the Processing Foundation discussion board. The answer seems to be that there is no VPAT but it is being worked on. That discussion has some intesting links about how to make Processing more color-blind friendly, and also refers to some work being done in the related p5.js world (where a [p5.accessibility](https://github.com/processing/p5.accessibility) library is being developed). Since Processing is a programming language for the visual arts, it isn't clear how it could work for people who are totally blind